# How long should a graduate school statement of intent be?

Tags: graduate-admissions, statement-of-purpose, chemistry

I'm attempting to apply to a graduate program for medicinal chemistry and the prompt for the statement of intent doesn't explicitly state a page length. Should I assume about one page? And are paragraphs generally single spaced or double spaced?

Comment: A rule of thumb that is in my opinion useful is: keep things reasonably short. Nobody would be keen to read pages of vague statements. After all it (hopefully) is not about the length, but about what you write.

Comment: Always an option: contact the institution and ask them. Getting a SOI of their preferred length is also in their interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the program, but if no requirement is set, I would go for about 500 words. That's about two pages double-spaced. You want to be to the point in these essays. Too much rambling may turn the reader off.

I never turn anything in single-space. Double-spaced documents help for readability. It's up to you, but I suggest double-spacing.